# What do you think about using UUID v5 to make REST API (POST) Idempotent?

Tags: database, rest, post, uuid, idempotent

If a request fails, HTTP POST is normally not idempotent (executing a failed request again might cause multiple inserts). What do you think about using the users session id as UUID v5 "namespace" and the JSON payload as the "name"? It would result in the same ID for multiple requests and the database would reject an additional insert.

Answer (score 2):

There are APIs that specifically mark HTTP methods that are otherwise non-idempotent as idempotent.

POST being non-idempotent by default does not mean it's not allowed to be that, it just means that generic clients can't assume they are.

The best implementation I've seen is the Stripe API, that uses an `Idempotency-Key` as a HTTP header. The client defines this, and if 2 requests are received with an identical id, stripe knows how to handle the second. I think this is the best approach, and better than the idea of trying to construct a hash based on the request. A request *looking* identical does not mean the effect is the same, consider for example this `POST` request:

```
POST /increment
Content-Type: application/json

{ "increment-by": 2 }
```

If I send this request twice, I expect some id to be increased to 4, even if the request body was the same each time.

The `Idempotency-Key` lets a client control and inform the server if 2 requests were actually the same.

https://stripe.com/blog/idempotency

Followups:

> Do I store the Idempotency-key as a separate column on the record?

I would be inclined to implement this feature globally as some kind of middleware.

> Storing the Idempotency-key in something like Redis yields the risk of two realities (e.g. server creates db record and crashes before writing to Redis).

Use a transaction.

All you have to store about the key is that you've seen it before, and you only have to store it if the request was successful.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I've read that article before but I'm unsure how to implement it. Do I store the Idempotency-key as a separate column on the record? If so, I could just do client-side ID generation (UUID v4) instead of server side. It has the same effect. Storing the Idempotency-key in something like Redis yields the risk of two realities (e.g. server creates db record and crashes before writing to Redis). Do you have an idea?